# "Connection problem or invalid MMI code" in Samsung SHV-E160L

Tags: connection-issues

I have bought a Samsung SHV-E160L in the Philippines. Lately, I have been facing problems with  signal reception. The SIM card is good because it works on another phone. Could it be the problem on the phone? I am not good at Android terms so please be specific.

The signal bar sometimes is full but cannot make call or text. It sometimes work but mostly it doesn't even if it is showing full strength. It just says "Connection problem or invalid MMI code", and sometimes there's no signal totally  even if the signal is very strong. I took my phone to a  technician but he couldn't find a working solution. I am really getting frustrated because I cannot make calls most of the time and others cannot contact me.